# Waiting for an Async task to complete

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have three classes,

1. Class A (Extends Activity. This is the main Activity)
2. Class B (Extends Async. This is used to login)
3. Class C (Extends Activity. This is to be called once the Async task from Class B is complete)

Within my main activity (A), I am executing Class B's login methods.
After these login methods run I want to open up the 2nd activity which is Class C. I can't do this right now as while Class B runs Class C opens. I need it to wait for the Async task to complete.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I have already searched and from what i've gathered people haven't been trying to do it with the same class structure as me which changes things up a little.

Thanks

Comment: launch Activity C in Class B's onPostExecute?

Comment: Launch the second activity (class C) from `onPostExecute()` of your AsyncTask (class B)

Comment: Hey, I can't do this (I think) because Class B doesn't extend activity. So I don't have access to the Intent object etc. Unless i'm being really stupid and I can just import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your AsyncTask to stay in a separate file, you'll need to fetch the Context in the constructor. Then after you've done logging-in you can start Activity C.

Something like this:

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Context mContext;

    public LoginTask(Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Login here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // Start Activity C
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityC.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And in Activity A call this AsyncTask like this:

```
new LoginTask(this).execute();
```

Comment: Hey, You're right I want to keep Async in a separate file. I'll try this and get back to you!

Comment: Ok, So I tried it out and I can't get it to work :(. Basically I get told Intent cannot be resolved and I'm pretty sure this is because Class B doesn't extend activity. Any ideas?

Comment: @Arizoo `import android.content.Intent;` Use an IDE, it will basically do all the importing for you.

Comment: Thanks friend! I actually use Android Studio, no idea why it didn't auto import :P

Comment: @Arizoo Well it highlights classes that can be imported, and if you do so with the ALT+ENTER shortcut it will jump to the next class that can be imported.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Start C from `onPostExecute()` of B.

> because Class B doesn't extend activity

Your `AsyncTask` should be managed by a retained fragment, so it works properly across a configuration change. Make the `AsyncTask` be a regular inner class of that retained fragment, so it can call `getActivity()` safely from `onPostExecute()`, and it can call `startActivity()` on that.

Comment: Hi there,
So the best practise would be to create a fragment class which is basically invisible to the user?

Comment: @Arizoo: Sure. They're called "model fragments". You attach them to the activity via the `add()` method on `FragmentTransaction` that takes a tag instead of a container ID. Another option would be to get rid of the `AsyncTask` entirely and use greenrobot's EventBus. You would have an ordinary thread that would post a message to the bus, to be picked up by Class A in `onEventMainThread()`, to indicate when the login succeeded or failed. Class A would then start Class C or handle the error.

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for your help, I made this thread to find out about my question and have left much more knowledgeable thanks to you. I won't be using your greenrobot's Eventbus for this solution, or a model fragment however, I now have two great tools under my belt. Thanks a lot, a very informative post from yourself, and I will most definitely make use of your advice sometime in another implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Make B an inner class of A, then start C from `onPostExecute`. Since B is an inner class of A, you'll get access to everything in A.

Comment: Hi, My reasoning behind not creating a subclass was that I just wanted everything to be separate. As a new programmer I thought that was good practise.

Comment: The async task is part of your activity (or, as @CommonWare suggested - a fragment). An inner class is OK here.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code for the next activity in the postExecute of the class which extends the asynctask.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute()
{
   //code for changing the current activtiy    
}
```